# Laravel - Dropdown Pluck Data Cannot Get the String Value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a dropdown that the value of the dropdown is on another table .. and I plucked it so here it is I am getting **1** to display and not **Sample Client 3** value which the dropdown has.. help thanks.

See here my dropdown and its value

[image]

See my dropdown, when I choose **Sample Client** it will insert **0** and NOT the ACTUAL string why is that? please take a look at my code thanks

My ***Dropdown Input***

```
 {{Form::select('clients', $clients ,null,['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Select Movie Provider...'])}}
```

My ***Controller***

On create function here it is

```
$clients = Client::all()->pluck('client_name');
    return view('admin.movies.create', compact('clients'));
```

on ***View Index*** which I foreach loop here it is

```
 <td>{{$movie->movie_provider}}</td>
```

and my Database Model Relationship

On the ***CLIENT*** side

```
    class Client extends Model
{
     use SoftDeletes;

     protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
     // Table Name
     protected $table = 'clients';
     // Primary Key
     public $primaryKey = 'id';
     // Timestamps
     public $timestamps = true;
```

on the ***MOVIES*** side

```
     public function movies(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Movie');
     }
}

    class Movie extends Model
{
    // Table Name
    protected $table = 'movies';
    // Primary Key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function clients(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to be explicit about the value and label. Make your plucked data look like this:

```
[
    'Sample client' => 'Sample client',
    'Sample client 3' => 'Sample client 3',
]
```

by doing

```
// pluck(value, key)
$clients = Client::all()->pluck('client_name', 'client_name');
```

Documentation: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#drop-down-lists

Comment: Oh Right! :/ .. just like an Array, well im not familiar with Pluck eloquents in laravel sorry.. It works btw. thanks